# What 70s dystopian story has people segregated based on every physical characteristic?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once read a story, in the 70's, about the ultimate prejudice. It was science fiction, and it was a short story. If I remember right, it was in an anthology collection (e.g. *Best Sci-fi of the Year*, or something like that).

The plot was about people segregating each other based on everything and anything (race, height, hair color, left hand/right hand, eye color, etc.), nothing was too extreme. It was set in a future America, in an anonymous metropolitan city.

The story was written in the 70's or earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be "[All the Last Wars at Once](http://bookre.org/reader?file=222931)" by George Alec Effinger? That one starts with blacks and whites declaring a 30-day all-out war, after which everyone remaining will consider all grievances settled. It's followed by Women's Libbers declaring war on men, then Catholics versus Protestants, and it snowballs from there.